# How can I get number of clicks on a facebook share button per user using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I don't know whether this is possible but i want to count number of clicks on the facebook share button per person.Here is my code for a button

```
<div id="tryf" class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://grey.com/?  grey_try+points" data-layout="button"></div>
```

THIS IS WERE I Output number CLICKS

```
   <div id='output'>10</div>
```

my javascript

```
 <script>
    $('#tryf').click(function() {
    $('#output').html(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 });
   });
  </script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: May be, use cookies/localStorage?

Comment: You can't just do it by Javascript. Javascript is a client side scripting language.

Comment: @Java-DK And now what? If the information to be stored is a simple per-user counter, it could be stored on the client as well (using LocalStorage) or be sent to the server backend.

Comment: @feeela my count does not increment I don't know why.

Comment: Your code works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/8y0tbqbp/ are you sure that the fb button isn't in a frame, if so you will need to find the fb button in the frame and bind the click event to that (not sure if you can do this cross domain), or to the frame itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the click count somewhere. If it really is per person, it could be stored on the client PC in the browsers `localStorage`. This would display the number of clicks on the share button made from that specific PC and browser.

```
var shareButton = document.querySelector( '.fb-share-button' ),
    counterDisplay = document.querySelector( '#output' ),
    storageKey = 'fb-share-button-click-count',
    /* read the current click count from the localStorage (on page load) */
    clickCount = parseInt( localStorage.getItem( storageKey ) );

/* update UI */
counterDisplay.innerHtml = clickCount;

if( shareButton instanceof Element ) {
    shareButton.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
        /* increase click count and set it into the localStorage */
        localStorage.setItem( storageKey, ++clickCount );

        /* update UI */
        counterDisplay.innerHtml = clickCount;
    }, false );
}
```

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

You probably also want to send the click count to some server backend to store it in a database, but to do so, you also need a session handling to identify different users. But using a proper session handling or even a login to identify users, allows for switching the PC or browser. (Which does not work using `localStorage` alone).